# Difference in code coverage report generated by Visual studio and Azure Devops pipeline (using VStest with code coverage enabled)

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, code-coverage, difference, vstest

I have a pipeline to run Vstest task with code coverage enabled option. Report generating from pipeline is differs with visuals studio code coverage analysis report. And also report generated by pipeline by default it including third party assemblies but in VS it is not including third party assemblies.

Please advise how to get the same report in Azure devops pipeline?